# Adding Add method to ActiveRecord array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the models Category and Products. If I use `category.products << new_product` the item gets added to the array and the record is saved to the database. I tried adding the following "add" method to the array class and while it does adds the new_product to the array, it does not save it to the database. Why is that?

```
class Array
  def add(item)
    self << item
  end
end
```

**Update:**

collection_proxy.rb has the following method:

```
def <<(*records)
  proxy_association.concat(records) && self
end
alias_method :push, :<<
```

So the following extension works:

```
class ActiveRecord::Relation
  def add(*records)
    proxy_association.concat(records) && self
  end
end
```

**Solution:**

Add an alias to the CollectionProxy:

```
class ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy
  alias_method :add, :<<
end
```

Comment: Because Rails associations aren't arrays, they just claim they are.

Comment: What are they then? how can I add an "Add" method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** Manuel found a better solution

```
class ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy
  alias_method :add, :<<
end
```

**Original solution:**

This should get you started. It's not perfect.

```
class ActiveRecord::Relation
  def add(attrs)
    create attrs
  end
end
```

Rather than fire up a new rails project with your model names, I just used one I had for the following example:

```
1.9.3p194 :006 > Artist.create(:first_name => "Kyle", :last_name => "G", :email => "foo@bar.com")
 => #<Artist id: 5, first_name: "Kyle", last_name: "G", nickname: nil, email: "foo@bar.com", created_at: "2012-08-16 04:08:30", updated_at: "2012-08-16 04:08:30", profile_image_id: nil, active: true, bio: nil> 
1.9.3p194 :007 > Artist.first.posts.count
 => 0 
1.9.3p194 :008 > Artist.first.posts.add :title => "Foo", :body => "Bar"
 => #<Post id: 12, title: "Foo", body: "Bar", artist_id: 5, created_at: "2012-08-16 04:08:48", updated_at: "2012-08-16 04:08:48"> 
1.9.3p194 :009 > Artist.first.posts.count
 => 1
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know why it fails when you add the new record not as a hash but passing an object? (I'm getting "NoMethodError: undefined method `stringify_keys'")

Comment: @Manuel yes, `add` is calling `create` and it expects attributes as a hash. You could alter the method to something like `create item.attributes` but you may get some problems with protected attributes. Consider picking out the ones you need from the object.

Comment: Not quite :(  create item.attributes creates the record in the database but does not make the relation (in your case artist_id is null).

Comment: @Manuel Remove the relation `id` from the hash first. `item.attributes.delete(:category_id)`. It was set to `nil` and the create used that as the value. If it was missing from the hash, the relation would be setup.

Comment: We're almost there. Please see update. Do you know how to call the << method of the collection instead of copy/pasting its contents? I've tried many things to no avail.

Comment: should be able to use dot notation. `[1].<<(2) # => [1,2]`

Comment: Thanks for the help. It turns out that everything we were doing would have worked had we extended CollectionProxy instead. In the end I like the alias method route (the collection is already using the push alias).

Comment: @Manuel you're welcome. I'm glad I could get you moving in the right direction. Nice solution!